# SciFi book about a visitor to earth on a mission who pinches a motorbike off a biker gang

Tags: identification-request

A visitor to earth is on a mission, and is scouting or something.
He comments about a flatscreen display which although not 3D has an impressive picture. Arrives on earth and pinches a motorbike off a gang of bikers, comments on how fast it is even though crazy fools (us) are burning irreplaceable carbons to fuel it.

I read the first two books of the series some 30 years ago, but sadly not able to recall the name to locate. It is a series of several books.

Comment: Hi welcome to Literature stack exchange : you’ve provided helpful pointers re content of your book , additional help with the appearance , cover art , publisher , dates ( when you read it, when it was published ) are helpful .As a certain fictional dectective was won’t to say “ omit no detail however slight “ .This wiki is helpful with regard to  info to include 
https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info